# Restrucutre JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I'm fetching data from an API and I'm trying to restucture the data. I want the data te be structed in a type of JSON way. Like shown below.

I have tried alot but I find it very hard to do because for each methode and the for loops used.

How can I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appricated!

I want to make and change the output of the program to this type of json structure:

```
[ 

  { id: 'bitcoin',
  x: [1571695345012, 1571699061041, 1571702676146, 1571706278232, 1571709762429],
  y: [8222.065325961827, 8192.012381921422, 8220.91853113097, 8192.5487839435, 8184.743590188011] 
  }

  { id: 'ethereum',
  x: [1571695472168, 1571699049447, 1571702639502, 1571706279834, 571709827389],
  y: [174.5266477952419, 173.6409574561425, 174.35449608806442, 173.9800501560514, 173.99298281578433]
  }

  { id: 'ripple',
  x: [1571695472168, 1571699049447, 1571702639502, 1571706279834, 571709827389],
  y: [0.2926270710439499, 0.29225262544982944, 0.2922858993183195, 0.29169629356590593, 0.2926150467160304]
  }

]
```

This is the output I go right now:

```
[ { id: 'bitcoin' },
  { x: 1571695345012 },
  { x: 1571699061041 },
  { x: 1571702676146 },
  { x: 1571706278232 },
  { x: 1571709762429 },
  { y: 8222.065325961827 },
  { y: 8192.012381921422 },
  { y: 8220.91853113097 },
  { y: 8192.5487839435 },
  { y: 8184.743590188011 },
  { id: 'ethereum' },
  { x: 1571695472168 },
  { x: 1571699049447 },
  { x: 1571702639502 },
  { x: 1571706279834 },
  { x: 1571709827389 },
  { y: 174.5266477952419 },
  { y: 173.6409574561425 },
  { y: 174.35449608806442 },
  { y: 173.9800501560514 },
  { y: 173.99298281578433 },
  { id: 'ripple' },
  { x: 1571695366383 },
  { x: 1571699042366 },
  { x: 1571702671612 },
  { x: 1571706274116 },
  { x: 1571709875603 },
  { y: 0.2926270710439499 },
  { y: 0.29225262544982944 },
  { y: 0.2922858993183195 },
  { y: 0.29169629356590593 },
  { y: 0.2926150467160304 } ]
```

The code used:

```
    //Initialize unirest
var unirest = require("unirest");

//Combined array
var JSONApiData = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'ripple'];
var ApiSparkline = []; // *** Should this really be a module global??

function unirestp(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        unirest(...args).end(res => {
            if (res.error) {
                reject(res.error);
            } else {
                resolve(res.body);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function request() {
    console.log("waiting for the sparkline data...");
    // Runs the API requests in parallel
    const data = await Promise.all(JSONApiData.map(id =>
        unirestp("GET", `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=7`)
    ));
    // Promise.all guarantees that the result array is in the same order as the input array, so
    // we can rely on that when mapping the reults
    data.forEach((id, index) => {


        const {prices} = data[index];
        ApiSparkline.push({id: JSONApiData[index]});

        for (let j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {        // *** What if `prices` doesn't have 5 entries?
            ApiSparkline.push({x:prices[j][0]});
        }

        for (let j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {        // *** What if `prices` doesn't have 5 entries?
            ApiSparkline.push( {y:prices[j][1]});
        }
    });
    // Show object
    console.log(ApiSparkline);
}

//Call request function
request()
    .then(() => {
        // Done
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        // Handle/report error
    });
```

Comment: How about incoming data structure ? Can we see an example part of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only want to call `ApiSparkline.push` once per API call (ie forEach)

```js
//Initialize unirest
const unirest = require("unirest");

//Combined array
const JSONApiData = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'ripple'];

function unirestp(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        unirest(...args).end(res => {
            if (res.error) {
                reject(res.error);
            } else {
                resolve(res.body);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function request() {
    console.log("waiting for the sparkline data...");
    // Runs the API requests in parallel
    const data = await Promise.all(JSONApiData.map(id =>
        unirestp("GET", `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=7`)
    ));
    // Promise.all guarantees that the result array is in the same order as the input array, so
    // we can rely on that when mapping the reults
    const ApiSparkline = [];
    data.forEach((result, index) => {

        const { prices } = result;
        const id = JSONApiData[index];
        const x = prices.map(([xItem, yItem]) => xItem);
        const y = prices.map(([xItem, yItem]) => yItem);

        ApiSparkline.push({
            id,
            x,
            y
        });
    });
    return ApiSparkline;
}

//Call request function
request()
    .then(ApiSparkline => {
        console.log(ApiSparkline);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        // Handle/report error
    });
```